# Pass application.properties to Logback Custom Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

I use spring boot, i want to get application.properties attribute in custom filter of logback. I know how to get it in normally but this is quite different case for me.

my application.properties,

```
sample.name="firstName"
```

and logback-spring.xml contains,

```
<configuration>

    <property resource="application.properties" />

    <springProperty scope="context" name="firstName" source="sample.name"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>${logging.console.level:-ERROR}</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="com.xxx.xxx.logback.LogbackJsonEventLayout"/>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="com.xx.xx.logging.CriticalAlertLoggerFilter"/>

    </appender>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Created customer filter,

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply;

@Component
public class CriticalAlertLoggerFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

  public static final String ALERT_CRITICAL_STATUS = "CRITICAL";

  @Value("${firstName}")  // This is not working using @Value and not sure how to get it.
  private String name;

  @Override
  public FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent event) {
    if (event.getLevel().isGreaterOrEqual(Level.ERROR)) {
      MDC.put("sp-eventSourceUUID",name);

    return FilterReply.ACCEPT;
  }
}
```

am wondering how to get the properties value of sample.name in my customer filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter should not contain Spring annotations.  Create a setter method for the `name` property and set its value through your `logback-spring.xml` as follows:

```
<filter class="com.mycompany.logback.filter.CriticalAlertLoggerFilter">
    <name>${firstName}</name>
</filter>
```

It's just like `ThresholdFilter` in your example (it has a [`setLevel()`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/filter/ThresholdFilter.html#setLevel(java.lang.String)) method).

Comment: Well, if the answer solves your problem you should officially accept it by putting the green mark on it.

Comment: sorry i didn't click green button.

Comment: Just quick question, can i use the <name>${firstName}</name> for multiple filters? if so how please?

Comment: You can use the same variable (`${firstName}`, in this case) multiple times in the config file to set any property: simply include `${firstName}` in a tag that corresponds to a setter method.